# What's the best modern algorithm for recursive least squares?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, matrix-factorization, randomized-algorithms, update

Recursive least squares can be implemented using the Sherman–Morrison formula to avoid resolving, however, have better methods without $n^2$ cost been developed? I'm interested if there is a good randomized approach here.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Recursive least-squares filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter) has a section on lattice recursive least-squares filter that notes "it requires fewer arithmetic operations (order $N$)."  Is that of interest?

Comment: @hardmath I don't know that algorithm, but Wikipedia says that it is "related to RLS"; from the description in that paragraph I assume it's an algorithm that computes a different output, not just another algorithm to compute the RLS output.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni:  The post is open to "a good randomized approach", so perhaps the difference of parameters fitted is not crucial to the OP.  In any case if that algorithm is unknown to Torkoal but interesting, I'll write up something with references that will serve as a starting point.